# Google wave robot inline reply

Tags: python, google-wave

I've been working on my first robot for google wave recently, a vital part of what it does is to insert inline replies into a blip. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this!

The API docs have a function [InsertInlineBlip](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/waveapi.ops.OpBasedDocument-class.html#InsertInlineBlip) which sounded promising, however calling that doesn't appear to do anything!

EDIT::
It seems that this is a known bug. However, the question still stands what is the correct way to insert an inline blip? I'm assuming something like this:

```
inline = blip.GetDocument().InsertInlineBlip(positionInText)
inline.GetDocument().SetText("some text")
```

Comment: hehe, retagged from newbie to beginner, what's the scientific difference? ;)

Comment: "Newbie" can have negative connotations, I suppose.

Comment: number that follows beginner tag is 3051, newbie 60. that's all

Comment: The wave tag got removed. Eventually google wave won't just be a google product (like email is not the product of any specific company), hence I added the wave tag

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inline reply? Append an answer to the content of the blip or create a child blip?

Comment: An inline reply is one which is created in the middle of another blip.

If you have access to wave, create a blip, then put your cursor somewhere in the middle and press ctrl-enter, to create an inline reply.

You'll get something like this:
http://martindevans.appspot.com/file/WaveInline.png?agxtYXJ0aW5kZXZhbnNyEAsSCEJsb2JGaWxlGOHXAgw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [sourcecode](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/waveapi.ops-pysrc.html#OpBasedDocument.InsertInlineBlip) for `OpBasedDocument.InsertInlineBlip()` you will see the following:

```
 412 -  def InsertInlineBlip(self, position): 
 413      """Inserts an inline blip into this blip at a specific position. 
 414   
 415      Args: 
 416        position: Position to insert the blip at. 
 417   
 418      Returns: 
 419        The JSON data of the blip that was created. 
 420      """ 
 421      blip_data = self.__context.builder.DocumentInlineBlipInsert( 
 422          self._blip.waveId, 
 423          self._blip.waveletId, 
 424          self._blip.blipId, 
 425          position) 
 426      # TODO(davidbyttow): Add local blip element. 
 427      return self.__context.AddBlip(blip_data)
```

I think the TODO comment suggests this feature is not yet active. The method should be callable and return correctly, however I suspect that the document operation is not applied to the global document.

The syntax you included in your post looks correct.  As you can see above, `InsertInlineBlip()` [returns the value](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/waveapi.ops-pysrc.html#_ContextImpl.AddBlip) of `AddBlip()`, which is ...dun, dun, dun... a blip.

```
 543 -  def AddBlip(self, blip_data): 
 544      """Adds a transient blip based on the data supplied. 
 545   
 546      Args: 
 547        blip_data: JSON data describing this blip. 
 548   
 549      Returns: 
 550        An OpBasedBlip that may have operations applied to it. 
 551      """ 
 552      blip = OpBasedBlip(blip_data, self) 
 553      self.blips[blip.GetId()] = blip 
 554      return blip
```

EDIT:
It is interesting to note that the method signature of the Insert method `InsertInlineBlip(self, position)` is significantly different from the Insert method `InsertElement(self, position, element)`. `InsertInlineBlip()` doesn't take an element parameter to insert.  It seems the current logic for `InsertInlineBlip()` is more like `Blip.CreateChild()`, which returns a new child blip with which to work. From this we can suspect that this API will change as the functionality is added.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a possible [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-wave-resources/issues/detail?id=212).

Comment: Aha! I hope they release a fix soon :/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have previously been a bug, however, an update today has hopefully fixed it:
http://code.google.com/p/google-wave-resources/wiki/WaveAPIsChangeLog

Comment: Aha excellent, thankyou for pointing this out to me, it is indeed fixed now